# How to get proper spacing with \documentclass{scrartcl}

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I would really like to use [this cv template](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/classicthesis-styled-cv), but the problem it has is that the sentences don't fill up the entire space as illustred by this screenshot[image]

To clarify, the middle sentence clearly doesn't fill up the space compared with the last word of the first sentence "array". Does anybody know how I can change this?

This is how the document starts:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\reversemarginpar % Move the margin to the left of the page 

\newcommand{\MarginText}[1]{\marginpar{\raggedleft\itshape\small#1}} % New command defining the margin text style

\usepackage[nochapters]{classicthesis} % Use the classicthesis style for the style of the document
\usepackage[LabelsAligned]{currvita} % Use the currvita style for the layout of the document

\renewcommand{\cvheadingfont}{\LARGE\color{Maroon}} % Font color of your name at the top

\usepackage{hyperref} % Required for adding links   and customizing them
\hypersetup{colorlinks, breaklinks, urlcolor=Maroon, linkcolor=Maroon} % Set link colors

\newlength{\datebox}\settowidth{\datebox}{Spring 2011} % Set the width of the date box in each block

\newcommand{\NewEntry}[3]{\noindent\hangindent=2em\hangafter=0  \parbox{\datebox}{\small \textit{#1}}\hspace{1.5em} #2 #3 % Define a command for each new block - change spacing and font sizes here: #1 is the left margin, #2 is the italic date field and #3 is the position/employer/location field
\vspace{0.5em}} % Add some white space after each new entry

\newcommand{\Description}[1]{\hangindent=2em\hangafter=0\noindent\raggedright\footnotesize{#1}\par\normalsize\vspace{1em}} % Define a command for descriptions of each entry - change spacing and font sizes here

\begin{document}
```

Comment: You need to include more of the document for the problem to be fully diagnosed.  However, `\raggedright` behavior seems to be what you are hoping to avoid.  Such an invocation shows up once in the `\Description` macro.  Removing that command from the definition might help.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes thank you! That's exactly what I was looking for. If you post it as an answer, I'll happily accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seemed to me the OP's question had to do with the ragged right margin, based on his/her description of "sentences don't fill up the entire space".  As new LaTeX users discover, the default LaTeX behavior is for fully-aligned marginal justification.

However, various classes and code imported from elsewhere can override that.  The enabling macro to override the flush margins is `\raggedright`.  The small sample of code provided by the OP shows `\raggedright` in one location, the `\Description` macro.

I suggested removing that macro from `\Description` and the OP replied that the problem was resolved.

Here was the original definition:

```
\newcommand{\Description}[1]{\hangindent=2em\hangafter=0\noindent\raggedright\footnotesize{#1}\par\normalsize\vspace{1em}} % Define a command for descriptions of each entry - change spacing and font sizes here
```

producing the following result when `\Description` was invoked.

[image]

When `\raggedright` is removed from the `\Description` macro, the result is

[image]